# PDOException error while using php artisan migrate command in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to learn laravel 5. I am following the laracast tutorial but I got one problem. When I use the php artisan migrate command I get the error like this

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
```

Comment: Have you configured a mySQL database and entered the credentials in the config?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now, problem had been solved.